# Fortran I/O Descriptors in Java?

Tags: java, fortran, decimalformat

I'm currently having to interface with a legacy Fortran program by creating an ascii output file that the program needs to read in, perform some calculations, and then I have to parse the binary output. For the most part, I have this working, but I'm running into a slight snag.

The problem I'm running into is with Fortran descriptors. Is there an easy way I can get a descriptor like E9.3 into a DecimalFormat object in Java?

The DecimalFormat I have works only for numbers less than 1. For numbers < 1 such as 0.123,  they are written out with the sign on the exponential, as 1.230E-01. However, for numbers greater than 1 (12.345), they are written out as 1.234E01 rather than 1.234E+01. From what I'm being told, the program is expecting that '+' sign as part of the exponential.

The DecimalFormat string I'm currently using is "#0.000E00", and I'm currently pulling some string manipulation to insert the '+' in there (after the E but before the digits) if necessary. There has to be a better way to do this. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: `String.format("%e", 123.456);` returns `1.234560e+02` for me.

Comment: The problem is that the total string needs to be 9, and only 9, characters long. Essentially, the example number of yours would need to be 1.235E+02, and I'm unsure how to force it to a certain length.

Comment: Looking at the DecimalFormat spec (I've never personally used it), it seems rather inflexible.  No obvious trick to achieve what you want other than post-processing.

Comment: @K.Niemczyk I'm not familiar with Fortran, so I just focused on the part of the problem you explained. I'll see about making a more complete answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you really sure you need this? Maybe it's only a compiler extension, but it's worth checking if the Fortran program actually accepts your form 1.234E01. My both compilers (gfortran and Solaris Studio) do accept them with E9.3 edit descriptor.

Comment: It turns out there was a miscommunication in our spec. The legacy system takes it either way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the source of the fortran program, you could change it to read the input file using the `*` descriptor, e.g. if you read in an array `data` of `n` values, e.g. change this:

```
read(iUnit,'(10E9.3)') data(10)
```

to something like:

```
read(iUnit, *) data(10)
```

or to write the file unformatted and then read in the binary data.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the whole string to be 9 characters, it means there'll be three characters left for the decimal part. You can express this with `printf` style formatting like this:

```
groovy:000> String.format("%.3E", 0.000123456789)         
===> 1.235E-04
groovy:000> String.format("%.3E", 1234.56789)         
===> 1.235E+03
```

If you need it to be nine characters in total even for negative numbers, with the leading '-' counting against the character count, you'll have to us an `if` to use a different format for negative numbers.